# Jquery Onclick functions wont work on second datatable's other pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sweetalert2

I have this datatables on my php but the jquery onclick functions only works properly on the first page but not the others.

the view data using modal works fine and the deleting of data as well but only on the first page

this is my buttons

```
<button type="button" id="<?php echo $row["Member_ID"]; ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm view_member_data">
    <i class="bi bi-eye-fill"></i>
</button>
<button type="button" id="<?php echo $row["Member_ID"]; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_member_data">
    <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
</button
```

> 

the command for viewing and deleting data:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.delete_member_data').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "delete_members.php",
                        method: "post",
                        data: {
                            employee_id: employee_id
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            Swal.fire(
                                'Deleted!',
                                'Member successfully deleted.',
                                'success'
                            ).then((result) => {
                                window.location.reload(true);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.view_member_data').click(function() {
            var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: "view_member_data.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {
                    employee_id: employee_id
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#employee_detail').html(data);
                    $('#dataModal').modal("show");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready` is called just once and the `.click` event is binded only to the current DOM, you have to call `.click` again after you load new data to the page, the modal should not work either (unless the script which call `.click` is part of the modal data)

Comment: As above, re-execute your jQuery that applies the behavior to the new elements after they have loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a global variable for employe_id, then add employe_id when clicking on the button.

Buttons

```
<button type="button" onclick="set_employee_id(<?php echo $row["Member_ID"]; ?>)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm view_member_data">
    <i class="bi bi-eye-fill"></i>
</button>
<button type="button" onclick="set_employee_id(<?php echo $row["Member_ID"]; ?>)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_member_data">
    <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
</button>
```

JS

```
<script>

var employee_id;
function set_employee_id(id){
    employee_id = id;
}

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.delete_member_data').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "delete_members.php",
                        method: "post",
                        data: {
                            employee_id: employee_id
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            Swal.fire(
                                'Deleted!',
                                'Member successfully deleted.',
                                'success'
                            ).then((result) => {
                                window.location.reload(true);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        });
    });


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.view_member_data').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "view_member_data.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {
                    employee_id: employee_id
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#employee_detail').html(data);
                    $('#dataModal').modal("show");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you are right that he shouldn't use `employee_id` inside attribute `id` but imo better way is to use attribute `data-id` for it

Comment: Yes, i think my answer will work properly and fix the problem. I've done it like this multiple times.